# A syntax error in my C18 program code

Tags: microcontroller, pic

I'm using the MPLAB IDE X v1.41 with C18 compiler to pragram a PIC18F45K20. My objective is to retrieve image data from a completely built image sensor board and display on the computer using the MAX232 and serial to USB cable. The output data of the image sensor is in a digital form. However, there was an error in my program code which stopped me from further testing. Please help me identify the problem.

The error occurs in the `putsUSART()` line in `void main(void)`

The program code below was written by myself. Notice that it is only the main body of the program:

```
//----------------------------Global variable----------------------------
unsigned int input0, input1, input2, input3, input4, input5, input6, input7;

//----------------------------USART initialize----------------------------
void init_USART(void)
{
    OpenUSART ( USART_TX_INT_OFF    &
                USART_RX_INT_OFF    &
                USART_ASYNCH_MODE   &
                USART_EIGHT_BIT     &
                USART_CONT_RX       &
                USART_BRGH_HIGH,
                25                  );
}

//----------------------------Main program----------------------------
void main(void)
{
    TRISB = 1;                  //input PORT B
    init_USART();
    while(1)
    {
        input0 = PORTB;
        putsUSART("%d",input0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this the whole file? Shouldn't there be some #includes at the top?

Comment: And what exactly is the error message you got?

Comment: This is really just a very basic C question, would fit better on SO, but you have your answer.

Comment: @GradyPlayer I don't think it is a completely C question. Yes, it involves major stuff that belongs to SO, however, it requires 8-bit PIC specific background to answer.

Comment: no more so than knowing `int sqlite3_column_count(sqlite3_stmt *pStmt);` requires the sqlite3.h header

Answer (score 4):

To use the USART library calls (OpenUSART and related flags), you'll need to #include the USART library header:

```
#include <usart.h>
```

You likely will also need the processor-specific #include, since the libraries support multiple flavours of parts and need a hint as to which hardware you're using:

```
#include "p18f45k20.h"
```

You may have to explicitly define the paths to these headers if your C18 isn't cooperating.

Also, further to what Abdullah said, user functions like your init_USART should have a function prototype in your primary .h file to avoid having to explicitly structure your code in a specific sequence.

```
void init_USART(void);
```

UPDATE: The error is in putsUSART.

According to the [library documenation](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/51297c.pdf), the call to putsUSART does not accept format specifiers like printf() and other standard I/O calls, it only accepts a pointer.

[image]

It appears that you need to sprintf() into a string buffer first, then call putsUSART on that buffer.

Comment: The other answers may allow compilation, but this is correct, you shouldn't be redefining library interfaces in you main file.

Comment: Hi, I've did as Abdullah said(move function init_USART(void) above main(void)) but a syntax error still occurs. Many thanks for helping.

Comment: If you would actually specify what syntax error you're getting, we could help more.

Comment: Hi Madmanguruman, I've changed the code as shown above. The error displayed was "too many arguments in function call" which occur in line putsUSART().

Comment: You should update the question with this, not post it as a comment.

Comment: I've solved the error in my program. Thanks for all the help. =)

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have used an undefined function in the main. You have two solutions to this problem, both of them will work;

1. Move the function `init_USART(void)` above `main(void)`.
2. Add `void init_USART(void);` before `void main(void)`.

Also, you should do some inclusions to your C file with `#include` directive, as Madmanguruman noted.

Comment: What a tangled web we weave. :)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Can't wait to try again!
Again, many thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not a function call:

```
init_USART(void);
```

It's a mixture of an old-style function declaration with an implied return type and a new-style function declaration with `void`. To call a function that takes no arguments, just call it:

```
init_USART();
```

These days, though, as others have said, you should either add a declaration of that function in front of `main` or move its definition in front of `main`. The declaration would look like this:

```
void init_USART(void);
```

Comment: It it perfectly acceptable to return void from a pic firmware's main function... Won't even raise a warning.

Comment: @GradyPlayer - you're right; it's a freestanding implementation, not a hosted implementation, so there are fewer constraints. Fixed.